# How to achieve this Unity special effect?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, virtual-reality, oculus

I don’t know how to describe this except to show this video of the Oculus Rift tutorial “First Contact” - https://youtu.be/y0f8HskKvU0

When the user reaches into the computer screens in the experience, the screens distort (they glitch in static around the Oculus avatars hand, in reds and blues). It’s as if you can reach your hand into the “pixels” that make up the videos on the screens

I have no idea how to achieve this/what’s possible. Right now I have my screens set up like this- 1. A pane of Unity glass material over 2. A cube with a render texture of my video, in albedo and emissive.

How would I achieve this screen distortion/glitch effect around the users hand when they reach into a computer screen in my game?

Comment: Its a kind of intersection shader.

Comment: Do you have any reference links you can provide?

Comment: theres about 30 ways of doing it, use whichever feels comfortable. if you don't know any, keep learning, whatever we suggest will just stop you from exploring other options

Comment: @zambari ok, but this question is my way of trying to discover what those options are. I can't learn if I have nothing to go off of except the oculus demo - where can I find some of these 30 options?

Comment: oops I managed to send an answer before filling the points. Theres a few aspects here. one is : how do you know that the hand is near - you can measure distance, measure intersections, raycast in a few ways etc. This way you obtain hand proximity as input data. Now you need to use it as a mask to expose underlaying random process, i.e. turbulennt noise, or perlin noise (turbulent noise is very close to perlin noise where you use the noise values to offset uv mapping of the original noise instead of using it straight as colour values). you'd probably want to do it all in a shader

Comment: What have you tried so far?